# Optimize this query on a very big table

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I would like to optimize a SQL query (postgre) which is very long, on a very large tables.

The query is very simple :

```
select pi2.*  
from preval_item pi2
join preval_shipment ps on ps.pvs_shipping_number = pi2.pvs_shipping_number
where ps.pvs_shipping_date < to_date('09/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  and ps.shs_id = '30';
```

The table `preval_items` contains 46 million rows (and 39G data), and `preval_shipment` contains 340 000 rows (and 100M data).

There are correct indexes on the both tables.

The query takes more than 15 minutes.

I tried to tranform the query like that :

```
with pvs as materialized (
select pi2.*
from preval_item pi2
join preval_shipment ps on ps.pvs_shipping_number = pi2.pvs_shipping_number
where
    ps.pvs_shipping_date < to_date('09/01/2022','DD/MM/YYYY')
    and ps.shs_id = '30'
)
select pi.pvs_shipping_number
from preval_item pi
join pvs on pvs.pvs_shipping_number = pi.pvs_shipping_number;
```

Without success.

But what is interesting in this last query is that we can clearly see that the intermediate select (see the **with pvs as materialized**....) takes only a few seconds. It's really the join between these 2 tables that is very expensive.

When I do an explain, I obtain this (but hard to interprete for me) :

```
Merge Join  (cost=13845931.39..950104909.06 rows=62349421560 width=11)                                                                       |
  Merge Cond: ((pvs.pvs_shipping_number)::text = (pi.pvs_shipping_number)::text)                                                             |
  CTE pvs                                                                                                                                    |
    ->  Gather  (cost=16337.02..7189241.05 rows=29442834 width=821)                                                                          |
          Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                 |
          ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=15337.02..4243957.65 rows=12267848 width=821)                                                        |
                Hash Cond: ((pi2.pvs_shipping_number)::text = (ps.pvs_shipping_number)::text)                                                |
                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on preval_item pi2  (cost=0.00..4177367.72 rows=19524672 width=821)                                    |
                ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=14234.83..14234.83 rows=88175 width=11)                                                             |
                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on preval_shipment ps  (cost=0.00..14234.83 rows=88175 width=11)                                 |
                            Filter: (((shs_id)::text = '30'::text) AND (pvs_shipping_date < to_date('09/01/2022'::text, 'DD/MM/YYYY'::text)))|
  ->  Sort  (cost=6656689.78..6730296.87 rows=29442834 width=38)                                                                             |
        Sort Key: pvs.pvs_shipping_number                                                                                                    |
        ->  CTE Scan on pvs  (cost=0.00..588856.68 rows=29442834 width=38)                                                                   |
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.56..987588.70 rows=46859212 width=11)                                                                             |
        ->  Index Only Scan using idx_shipping_number on preval_item pi  (cost=0.56..870440.67 rows=46859212 width=11) 

                  |
```

Should I conclude that it is the volume that is at fault and that there is no other solution than to wait?

Edit:
The constraints definition. We see the pk on "pvs_shipping_number"

[image]

[image]

Comment: "There are correct indexes on the both tables." what indexes? Please show the full definitions for both tables.

Comment: As text not images, and please include the *full* DDL definition of the tables and indexes including all columns. Note that constraints and indexes are two different things.

Comment: For this to perform efficiently, I would have expected an index `preval_shipment (shs_id, pvs_shipping_date) INCLUDE (pvs_shipping_number)`

Comment: It's difficult to give more (confidentiality constraints with my company). But I think the main concern is "only" the volume of this table. You can confirm ? or diffcult to answer without the details of the 2 tables ?

Comment: You can anonymize the column names, like `CourseId` and `StudentId` or something like that. The idea is to compare your query with the columns and indexes, what the actual names are is irrelevant. As I said, we need the info on indexes. No I don't think the size of the table is an issue with the right indexes.

Comment: "we can clearly see that the intermediate select (see the with pvs as materialized....) takes only a few seconds"  I can't clearly see that. Is that coming from info you haven't shown us?

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` to get the execution and the plan? And also for the CTE without the `materialized` option. By the way, the current plan expects 62349421560 records to find. 62 billion, that is more or less correct?

Answer (score 1):

Correct indexes would be :

```
CREATE INDEX X001 ON preval_shipment (shs_id, pvs_shipping_date, pvs_shipping_number);
CREATE INDEX X002 ON preval_item (pvs_shipping_number);
```

In the exact order of columns in the key or reversing shs_id and pvs_shipping_date depending on the dispersion of the data.

Why is ps.shs_id set as a litteral '30' in the WHERE clause ? Is it a string or a number ?

Comment: Indies "X001" has been added (the X002 was already present). And now the query runs in 5 minutes. Much better ! But I fear that we cannot do better, given the volume of this table.

Comment: @Dom, you can try to parallelize the query but due to the fact that PostGreSQL does not run in a thread model but in a process model, parallelizing queries is really an exhausting sport with low performance. Also no compression nor vertical indexes does exists in PG contrary to SQL Server as an example...

Comment: I would think there's no need in this case to put `pvs_shipping_number` in the key, you could do `CREATE INDEX X001 ON preval_shipment (shs_id, pvs_shipping_date) INCLUDE (pvs_shipping_number);`

Comment: @Charlieface because pvs_shipping_number  is in the JOIN predicate, it needs to be in the index key... not in the include part of the index def....

Comment: No, it's going to use a range seek on `pvs_shipping_date` so `pvs_shipping_number` will already be out of order, therefore it doesn't help to put it in the key. Otherwise if you want to keep that ordering then it would be better to flip it to  `preval_shipment (shs_id, pvs_shipping_number) INCLUDE (pvs_shipping_date)` and rely on a Residual Predicate on `pvs_shipping_date`.